# Minecraft server connecting to site

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, hosting

I'm thinking about making a server where there is team of 8 vs team of 8. and I'm wondering if I can make a website where you register your team and it's members usernames, and it tells the server that these 8 people are on a team and play together as one, in a sense.  Does anyone know if this is possible? If this is unclear, tell me, and I'll try and explain better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not with vanilla

You'd need to make a server plugin, or find one that's close enough to what you need that you can customise, or just find one that someone else has released which does what you need

Comment: Could the down-voter here also please explain the down-vote?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup up:

- Bukkit Server
- Web Server
- Database

Then either custom make or have someone make you a plugin, or find one as "Jon Story" said.
Finally you will need to integrate it all using PHP.  While it is possible to do, learning Java, and PHP is much more work than just setting up a team selector in game.

Answer (score -2):

I have played Minecraft for many years and i have not yet seen this.. (It would be awesome!)

You could get a simple white list plugin that you can put on your website..

Then simply use command blocks and scoreboards to assign people to a random team...

This is not exactly what you wanted but it is the the best you can do without hardcore coding or mods :)

Comment: I'm using a bukkit server.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think there is a plugin to do this..

Comment: Could the down-voter explain why the down-vote?